# laravel 5 stripe при удалении подписки на триальном периоде, статус подписки пользователя не меняется

Tags: laravel, биллинг

Тестирую встроенную систему оплаты в laravel 5.5 cashier используя платежный сервис stripe в тестовом режиме. Все работает сейчас на удаленном сервере на Linux

Если я ставлю при подписке некоторый короткий триальный период, а затем удаляю подписку методом cancelNow(), то метод user()->subscribed() отдает true и onTrial отдает true. При наступление момента trial_ends_at ничего не меняется, тк в ЛК stripe при этом выставляется счет на оплату, который в тестовом режиме бывает оплачен далеко не сразу и триал период все длится.

Привожу отладку:

```
    dd(
        "cancelled", $request->user()->subscription('main')->cancelled(),
        "onTrial", $request->user()->subscription('main')->onTrial(),
        "onGracePeriod", $request->user()->subscription('main')->onGracePeriod(),
        "Subscibied", $request->user()->subscribed('main')
    ); 

    В состоянии после заказа подписки с триалом. и до отмены:

    "cancelled"
       false
    "onTrial"
       true
    "onGracePeriod"
       false
    "Subscribed"
       true

    В состоянии после нажатия кнопки вызывающий метод user->cancelNow()

    "cancelled"
        true
    "onTrial"
        true
    "onGracePeriod"
        false
    "Subscribed"
        true


    В ЛК stripe подписка отменена. 
    В БД подписка окончена:

        select u.stripe_id, u.stripe_plan, u.trial_ends_at, u.ends_at, u.created_at, u.updated_at from nofiles55.subscriptions u where user_id=11;
        +--------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
        | stripe_id          | stripe_plan | trial_ends_at       | ends_at             | created_at          | updated_at          |
        +--------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
        | sub_BQGWa9eBPWvlcH | silver_day  | 2017-09-18 14:14:40 | 2017-09-18 14:27:23 | 2017-09-18 14:12:47 | 2017-09-18 14:27:23 |
        +--------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

В такой ситуации пользователь уже не сможет что либо сделать, так как возобновлять подписку в Триал периоде нельзя. В тоже время заново он подписаться также не сможет учитывая, что по признаку Subscribed подписка у него уже есть. А в моем проекте я делаю, что бы у юзера в данный момент была только одна активная подписка и менять это конечно не нужно.
Да и вообще после сancelNow подписка должна ведь быть полностью удалена?

Что тут можно сделать? Возможно просто не давать отменять подписку юзеру в триал-периоде? Но он казалось бы должен иметь такую возможность...